# How can I programmatically set the options for a views exposed filter?

Tags: views, forms, 9

While it is possible to use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() to programmatically set the options for any select input, with a views exposed filter there is the added complication of not knowing how Drupal will interpret the values.  For example, if the filter is based on a taxonomy field, one cannot simply set the option values to the relevant term IDs. Doing so results in a select filter that doesn't work at all, because Drupal uses an intermediary value in a views select filter that somehow points to the actual desired value (the term ID, in this case).

Given this indirect use of select option values, how can I set the values programmatically in a way that agrees with Drupal's internal logic, so that the select input works as expected?

I presume this would involve setting up a mapping of option value to the intended value, as we do in the GUI:

[image]

In the GUI example above, the select option value would be 1, and Drupal internally knows that an option value of 1 corresponds to a term ID of 32.  How do I implement this programmatically?

Drupal version: 9.5.1